# Powershell export an imported CSV as fixed record length with no delimiter?

Tags: powershell, csv, export, fixed

I have a pretty standard CSV file which could look something like this:

```
heading1,heading2,heading3
aaaaaaaaa,bb,ccccccc
d,eeeeeeee,ff
gggggggg,hh,iiiiiiiiiii
```

This file is imported to an object using import-csv. I now want to export that object to a file which has a fixed record length with no delimiters and no table headers. If the imported values are too long for the fixed file, they should be cut off. It the imported values are too short, the values should be left aligned and filled with spaces.

Assuming the width of:

```
heading1 is 5
heading2 is 2 
heading3 is 10
```

basically the output should look like this:

```
aaaaabbccccccc   
d    eeff        
ggggghhiiiiiiiiii
```

Please note the spaces at the end of the values in column3.

The algorithms should not be completely inefficient - it will be used for converting a 300MB csv file.

I searched on Stackoverflow and googled for while and could find some related questions using solutions like a custom table format and format-table, but these solutions did not seem to be easily adaptable for me to this specific problem.

As to why: this very ugly/unusual format is required by a niche COTS software.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you going to do with such strange an output?

Comment: Have you written anything at all yet?

Comment: I would suggest looking at formatted strings `'{0,20}' -f 'Foo'`

Comment: @EBGreen: yes I have written a bit, as mentioned some import-csv with some piping, selecting, rearranging, etc.) I actually thought about adding that to my question. However I decided against including it in the question as it would have only made the question longer without adding any additional information.

Comment: Adding information like what you have tried and specifically the code that you have tried does three things (for me at least). Sometimes the question deals with systems that I am unfamiliar with. The Powershell I know but there may be some module that you are using that I am not familiar with. Seeing your code lets us answer in a way that fits your situation. Another consideration is that often seeing the code will point out some aspect of the question that was not clear in the normal language version of the question. Lastly, it tells us what your knowledge level is so we can better answer

Comment: I absolutely understand your points. Not wanting to start a meta discussion (I am new here after all :-)) however I purposely reduced the actual, more complex issue I have to this simple and understandable small core problem. The intricacies of the actual problem and related code would have made this question only harder to read and would have made the answers harder to reuse for others having a similar issue. Nonetheless I agree with you that showing the code has some advantages and will keep this in mind should I have future questions :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
## Q:\Test\2018\07\10\SO_51265871.ps1
$SPC = '                           ';
Import-Csv .\Input.csv | 
  ForEach-Object {"[{0}{1}{2}]" -f ($_.heading1+$SPC).Substring(0,5),
                                   ($_.heading2+$SPC).Substring(0,2),
                                   ($_.heading3+$SPC).Substring(0,10)
  } | Set-Content .\Output.rec
```

The `[]` in the format string are just to show the length including trailing spaces.

Sample output:

```
PS> Get-Content .\Output.rec
[aaaaabbccccccc   ]
[d    eeff        ]
[ggggghhiiiiiiiiii]
```

**EDIT: a variant a bit more general**, feeding column width from an array - same output

```
$CW = @(5,2,10) # array CW = ColumnWidth
Import-Csv .\Input.csv | ForEach-Object { $i = 0
  "[{0}{1}{2}]" -f `
    ($_.heading1).PadRight($CW[$i]).Substring(0,$CW[$i++]),
    ($_.heading2).PadRight($CW[$i]).Substring(0,$CW[$i++]),
    ($_.heading3).PadRight($CW[$i]).Substring(0,$CW[$i])
  } #| Set-Content .\Output.rec
```

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but this looks pretty clean, not totally inefficient and readable. Will try it soon and give feedback.

Comment: Indeed, this works nicely. Thanks. I am accepting this as the answer unless something even nicer / faster comes along. You might however want to uncomment the Set-Content bit in the second version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why you would want to do this but hey you do so fair play.

I think I catch what youa re trying to do and this will give you an array with each line being that processed data into the format you wanted, you can then loop that array into a txt file, log file, whatever you want.

```
$spacerCSVFile = "spacers.csv"
$prinspacerCSV = Import-Csv $spacerCSVFile -header "1","2","3"
$processedArray = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
foreach($row in $prinspacerCSV) {
    if ($row.1 -like "heading*") {
        # do nothing for headings
    } else {
        $item1 = $row.1
        $item2 = $row.2
        $item3 = $row.3

        while ($item1.length -lt 6) {
            $item1 += " "
        }
        while ($item2.length -lt 3) {
            $item2 += " "
        }
        while ($item3.length -lt 11) {
            $item3 += " "
        }
        if ($item1.length -gt 5) {
            $item1 = $item1.substring(0,5)
        }
        if ($item2.length -gt 2) {
            $item2 = $item2.substring(0,2)
        }
        if ($item3.length -gt 10) {
           $item3 = $item3.substring(0,10)
        }
        $processedArray += ,"$item1$item2$item3"
    }
}
foreach ($item in $processedArray) {
    write-host $item
}
```

I would advise however that it is worth giving it a go and coming here with some code in place first as the idea of stack overflow is to help with your code not provide it.

Answer (score 0):

This is very ugly and might be more complicated than what it needs to be but this is working from what I can tell.

Hope this gives you either an idea or this just helps

```
$file = "C:\Logs\Test.csv"

$data = Import-Csv $file

$properties = $data | 
              Get-Member | 
              Where-Object MemberType -EQ NoteProperty | 
              Select Name

foreach ($line in $data){

    [string]$dataout = $null

    foreach ($property in $properties) {
        $dataout = $dataout + $line.($property.Name)
    }

    if($dataout.Length -eq 20){
        $dataout
    }
    elseif ($dataout.Length -lt 20) {        
        Do{
            $dataout = $dataout + " "            
        }
        Until($dataout.Length -eq 20)
        $dataout        
    }
    else {
        $dataout = ($dataout.Substring(0,20))
        $dataout        
    }
}
```